# C++ CreateProcess redirect output only

Tags: c++, redirect, process

Please mind the word "only". There are many examples out there that redirect both input and output and I was able to do this but when I redirect only the output I do not get the expected behavior. I searched a lot but I couldn't find something similar. I am sure it is doable because I can do it in C#.
Using this code in C#:

```
Process process;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        process = new Process()
                      {
                          StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe")
                           {
                           UseShellExecute = false,
                           RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                           RedirectStandardError = true,
                           CreateNoWindow = false,
                           }
                      };
        process.OutputDataReceived += Process_OutputDataReceived;
        process.ErrorDataReceived +=Process_OutputErrorReceived;
        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();

        bool retval = AttachConsole(process.Id);
        while(true);

    }

    private void Process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

the program behaves as I expect. It creates and empty command window in which I am able to type commands and get their output in the Process_OutputDataReceived.
Trying to do the same thing in C++ using this code:

```
int main()
{
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES attributes;
attributes.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
attributes.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
attributes.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

HANDLE m_stdOutRead, m_stdOutWrite, m_stdErrorRead, m_stdErrorWrite;

if (!CreatePipe(&m_stdOutRead, &m_stdOutWrite, &attributes, 0) ||
    !CreatePipe(&m_stdErrorRead, &m_stdErrorWrite, &attributes, 0)) {
    return -1;
}

SetHandleInformation(m_stdOutRead, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
SetHandleInformation(m_stdErrorRead, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);

wchar_t cmdPath[MAX_PATH];
::GetEnvironmentVariable(L"COMSPEC", cmdPath, MAX_PATH);

STARTUPINFO si;
GetStartupInfo(&si);
si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOW;
si.hStdOutput = m_stdOutWrite;
si.hStdError = m_stdErrorWrite;

PROCESS_INFORMATION m_processInfo;
BOOL retval = ::CreateProcess(cmdPath,
    nullptr,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    TRUE,
    0,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &si,
    &m_processInfo);

while(true);
return 0;
}
```

does not do what I expect. The output is redirected indeed and I know that because I do get the "Microsoft Windows [Version blablabla" of the console output when I read the pipe but the command console window of the newly created process is closed immediately and I cannot still type commands in this and get the output. The process seems to still be running but where is the window? I would guess that this is happening because the command console window does not have an input handler at all (instead of using its own). But that is only a guess.  Any advise would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I think you should zero initialize startup info instead of using info for current process.

Comment: At the very least add `si.hStdInput = nullptr;`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions... I had already tried = nullptr and I also tried ::ZeroMemory but no luck